# Can I Stream the output with Capistrano 3 while the remote command is still running

Tags: capistrano3

I'd like to do the same as I could do with Capistrano2

```
task :memory do 
     run "free | awk '/^Mem:/{print $4}'" do | channel, stream, data |
          puts "host: #{channel[:host]} has free memory of #{data.to_i/1024} MB"
     end
end
```

Using **capture** wont help as it only prints after the remote command has finished.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: nope. This is to long ago and it seems to me that the world has moved to other approaches. sorry